# Unable to PhpUnit Test My Custom End Point

Tags: 8, testing

When I test my endpoint via POSTMAN, I don't have any problems. When I run my PhpUnitTest I keep getting 404:

```
1) Drupal\my_dashboard\Tests\Functional\MyDashboardResourceTest::testPost
Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 200.
```

rest.resource.snap_shots_resource.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - serialization
    - user
    - my_dashboard
id: snap_shots_resource
plugin_id: snap_shots_resource
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - POST
  formats:
    - json
  authentication:
    - cookie
```

SnapShotsResource.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_dashboard\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a resource to get view modes by entity and bundle.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "snap_shots_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Snap shots resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/snapshots",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/snapshots"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SnapShotsResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * A current user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Constructs a Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param array $serializer_formats
   *   The available serialization formats.
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   *   A logger instance.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
   *   A current user instance.
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('my_dashboard'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Responds to POST requests.
   *
   * @param array $data
   *   Data array.
   *
   * @return object
   *   Returns ResourceResponse.
   *
   * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
   *   Throws exception expected.
   */
  public function post(array $data = []) {
    $response = ['message' => $data];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }

}
```

Here is my Test class MyDashboardResourceTest:

```
namespace Drupal\my_dashboard\Tests\Functional;

use \Drupal\Tests\rest\Functional\ResourceTestBase;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;

/**
 * Tests the My Dashboard Resources.
 *
 * @group rest
 */
class MyDashboardResourceTest extends ResourceTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to install.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['hal', 'rest', 'user', 'serialization', 'my_dashboard'];

  public function testPost() {
    $this->initAuthentication();
    $this->setUpAuthorization('POST');

    $request_options = [];
    $request_options[RequestOptions::HEADERS]['Accept'] = static::$mimeType;
    $request_options[RequestOptions::HEADERS]['Content-Type'] = static::$mimeType;
    $request_options[RequestOptions::BODY] = '{}';
    $url = Url::fromUserInput('/snapshots');
    $response = $this->request('POST', $url, $request_options);
    $this->assertSame(200, $response->getStatusCode());
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUpAuthorization($method) {
    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        $this->grantPermissionsToTestedRole(['restful post snap_shots_resource']);
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getExpectedUnauthorizedAccessMessage($method) {
    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        return "The 'restful post snap shots resource' permission is required.";
      default:
        return parent::getExpectedUnauthorizedAccessMessage($method);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getExpectedBcUnauthorizedAccessMessage($method) {
    return "The 'restful " . strtolower($method) . " requires snapshots permission";
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertResponseWhenMissingAuthentication(ResponseInterface $response) {
    throw new \LogicException('When testing for anonymous users, authentication cannot be missing.');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertNormalizationEdgeCases($method, Url $url, array $request_options) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertAuthenticationEdgeCases($method, Url $url, array $request_options) {

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issue by not using the ResourceTestBase request method but creating the Client myself:

```
$url = Url::fromUserInput('/snapshots');
$url = $url->setAbsolute(TRUE)->toString();

$client = new Client();

$request_options = [];
$request_options[RequestOptions::HEADERS]['Accept'] = static::$mimeType;
$request_options[RequestOptions::HEADERS]['Content-Type'] = static::$mimeType;
$request_options[RequestOptions::BODY] = $this->getBody();

// Tests good post.
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, $request_options);
$this->assertSame(200, $response->getStatusCode());
$this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals(200);
```

Comment: Oh man i've been smashing my head over this issue for days. For some reason even just using their $this->getHttpClient() doesn't seem to work either.